# Apache Rewrite not working with domain name for Yii2 app in AWS Ubuntu OS

Tags: server, apache2, dns, webserver

If I open my Yii2 application with url http://IP_ADDRESS/DIR_NAME the it works perfectly. Now I have pointed my domain to path /var/www/html/. But if I open my domain in browser it displays my directory structure of yii2 project. So with http://IP_ADDRESS/DIR_NAME I could access my app but not with domain name. Apache rewrite is enabled for /var/www/html/ in 000-default.conf.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

-Content of 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

-Content of domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you fixed DocumentRoot parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent directory listing you should remove the Indexes keyword from your Options directive, or simply put a `-` in front of it like: `-Indexes`

Additionally, check your DocumentRoot with following command, it must match your Yii2 folder:

```
grep -i Documentroot /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Did you set the `ServerName` parameter in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` conf file? for example:

```
ServerName IP_ADDRESS
```

And always remember to reload configuration after you do changes

Comment: No I didn't set ServerName IP_ADDRESS in /var/www/html/ in 000-default.conf

Comment: and yes in my000-default.conf I have changed Documentroot  to /var/www/html/

Comment: and I have added one more conf file in sites-available to add virtual host for my domain. I have changed  Documentroot to /var/www/html/DIR_NAME/

Comment: Ok, and what's the situation now?

Comment: It's still not working. So I have two config file in sites-available first is 000-default.conf and second one is domain.conf. in 000 I have set Documentroot  to /var/www/html/ and in domain.com.conf I have set Documentroot   to /var/www/html/domain.com. also in 000-default.conf I have enabled apache rewrite to .../html/. I have no idea what I have done wrong. With Ip I can access my project. Please help me .

Comment: and where do I have to set ServerName parameter  and what should I set?

Comment: kindly, you should update your question and  add the contend of both files. 000-default.conf and domain.conf. Usually you make a VirtualHost file for a site. Not two like you did. But I can't suppose which one you should deactivate

Comment: thanks. I have updated my answer. Please tell me what can I change in this.

Comment: I would beginning by renaming 000-default.conf into 000-default.conf.off, in this way Apache httpd will not read this configuration file anymore whitout the .conf extension. To me it seems useless for you this Vhost. Then restart apache, test if now work, and let me know : )

Comment: One other thing then, is "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" a registered domain to a DNS authority? I don't think so. Is this the domain name which you want to use to access your website? this website will be accessed by you and only by you and only on from you local machine?

Comment: I added 
<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
</Directory>
in domain conf file and it worked. it's weird.

Comment: I am accepting your answer for helping me with this. thanks you so much. :)

Comment: welcome m8 ! peace

Comment: Oh one last things, I usually set DocumentRoot into the main configuration file of apache(/etc/apache2/conf/apache2.conf), since DocumentRoot can be one and only one in the whole apache server. A DocumentRoot paramenter should be already there, and if you look, a few line under it, there is a <Directory> entry, you should always set its path the same as the DocumentRoot set above. Telling you that because for me this is a best practice, and probably it would have avoided the little mistake of forgetting <directory> entry for your Root. ;)

Comment: Actually I avoid changing core files. I am still learning all these. thanks mate!!!